# Adding image into markdownfile

Tags: image, markdown

I am trying to add an image into a markdown file, for some reason, it is not working. Below are some of my tries at the code:

`{{< figure src="/images/CA.png" >}}`

`![C21A](CA.png)`

`<img src="CA.png" />`

Not sure why it isn't working, I think it something to do with the path but I cannot pinpoint it. The image is in the same folder as the markdown file.

Comment: The second one (`![C21A](CA.png)`) is correct. How to you view the rendered file and where is the whole thing located?

Comment: What do you render your Document with?

Comment: @AlexeyInkin I am using the text editor Atom, if that's what you mean

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl I am using the text editor Atom

Comment: @MarcusMiller and you are using a markdown preview in atom  I guess?

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl I'm using a localhost to preview

Comment: Yeah it's still not working, I am very confused

Comment: @MarcusMiller maybe try changing your preview? could be possible that your preview is unable to import local files

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl Hi thanks for getting back, I researched further and think there might be something wrong with preview like you mention. It seems it picks up urls so I will upload the images and take them from a github repository link

Comment: @MarcusMiller sounds like a valid workaround ;)